# Custom notifications for multiplayer invitation

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm looking for a way to customize default notifications that player receives from friend or other player. Currently there are only default notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must implement 
`com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationReceivedListener`.

Then you have to override `onInvitationReceived` to display a custom notification when you receieve an invitation.

It's just that simple. Any other questions don't hesitate to ask :)